# Different results reading tf.record of an image and the image directly

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to read an image to make predictions of my model, first probe doing a tf.record of the image that I wanted to predict with my model this is the code that decodes tf.record

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_path = '/Users/David/SA_TfRecord'  # address to save the hdf5 file

with tf.Session() as sess:
 feature = {'pred/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
           'pred/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

 # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
 filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)
 # Define a reader and read the next record
 reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
 _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

 # Decode the record read by the reader
 features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
 # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
 image = tf.decode_raw(features['pred/image'], tf.float32)

 # Cast label data into int32
 label = tf.cast(features['pred/label'], tf.int32)
 # Reshape image data into the original shape
 image = tf.reshape(image, [224, 224, 3])

# Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=1, 
capacity=30, num_threads=1, min_after_dequeue=1)
print(images)

# Initialize all global and local variables
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(init_op)
# Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

for batch_index in range(1):
    img, lbl = sess.run([images, labels])
    print(img)

# Stop the threads
coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to stop
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

I get this as a result of the decoding

```
[[[[ 53.  49.  66.]
   [ 53.  49.  66.]
   [ 53.  49.  66.]
   ...
   [ 68. 154. 171.]
   [ 68. 151. 167.]
   [ 69. 150. 167.]].......
```

with this code I make my tf.record

```
from random import shuffle
import glob
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys

shuffle_data = True  # shuffle the addresses before saving
data_path = '/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Sexta_Version_Combinacion/Direct/SA.jpg'
# read addresses and labels from the 'train' folder
addrs = glob.glob(data_path)

labels = [0 if 'CA' in addr else 1 for addr in addrs]  # 0 = Con Arms, 1 = Sin Arma
# to shuffle data
if shuffle_data:
    c = list(zip(addrs, labels))
    shuffle(c)
    addrs, labels = zip(*c)

# Divide the hata into 60% train, 20% validation, and 20% test
#train_addrs = addrs[0:int(0.8 * len(addrs))]
#train_labels = labels[0:int(0.8 * len(labels))]
#val_addrs = addrs[int(0.8 * len(addrs)):int(1 * len(addrs))]
#val_labels = labels[int(0.8 * len(addrs)):int(1 * len(addrs))]
pred_addrs = addrs[0:int(1 * len(addrs))]
pred_labels = labels[0:int(1 * len(labels))]

def load_image(addr):
    # read an image and resize to (224, 224)
    # cv2 load images as BGR, convert it to RGB
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    return img

def _int64_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))



pred_filename ='/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Sexta_Version_Combinacion/Direct/SA_TfRecord' # address to save the TFRecords file
# open the TFRecords file
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(pred_filename)
for i in range(len(pred_addrs)):
    # print how many images are saved every 1000 images
    if not i % 1:
        print 'pred data: {}/{}'.format(i, len(pred_addrs))
        sys.stdout.flush()
    # Load the image
    img = load_image(pred_addrs[i])
    label = pred_labels[i]
    # Create a feature
    feature = {'pred/label': _int64_feature(label),
               'pred/image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring()))}
    # Create an example protocol buffer
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

    # Serialize to string and write on the file
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then I want to put my image directly, so as not to make a tfrecord, but when I read it I get a different result. this is my code to read directly

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:

# Make a queue of file names including all the JPEG images files in the relative
# image directory.
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("/Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Sexta_Version_Combinacion/Direct/SA.jpg"))

# Read an entire image file which is required since they're JPEGs, if the images
# are too large they could be split in advance to smaller files or use the Fixed
# reader to split up the file.
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

# Read a whole file from the queue, the first returned value in the tuple is the
# filename which we are ignoring.
_, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

# Decode the image as a JPEG file, this will turn it into a Tensor which we can
# then use in training.
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)

image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])
image.set_shape((224, 224, 3))
print(image)

batch_size = 1
num_preprocess_threads = 1
min_queue_examples = 1
images = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image],batch_size=batch_size,num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,capacity=min_queue_examples+3*batch_size,min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)
print(images)



# Start a new session to show example output.

# Required to get the filename matching to run.
tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

# Coordinate the loading of image files.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

# Get an image tensor and print its value.
image_tensor = sess.run(images)
print(image_tensor)

# Finish off the filename queue coordinator.
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

I get this as a result

```
 [[[[ 51.  49.  63.]
   [ 52.  50.  64.]
   [ 51.  49.  63.]
   ...
   [ 66. 153. 170.]
   [ 67. 150. 166.]
   [ 68. 151. 167.]]........
```

I do not know what the error is, please help me,why I get different results??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because jpeg is a loss compression, it differs every time you save the image.

If you want the decode result be the same every time you read it, you can use other format, such as png, bmp, etc.